# How do you solve large dependencies among files?

Tags: refactoring, dependencies, dependency-analysis, files

So basically I make several programs. Of course one program often used code from another. So I have my own personal "library"

Well, I do write jerk codes. Then When I open a project, the project will require another file. I add that file and that file require another file, then I add that file and that file requires another file. Then, I ended up with so many files the program doesn't need. I ended up having to correct really really old codes that are no longer used on files I do not need. Why? Because I don't bother structure dependency. Well, subject for another question.

What do you do to avoid this problem.

Comment: I wonder why is this downvoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You modularize and make libraries.  Each library may contain much more than you will need in a project, but it is a single atomic unit that is easy to handle.

For starters, keep the library version number in the file name.

Remember to use a SCM like git.  It will be very helpful in the long run.